# Target column exceed 100 classes in ML classification

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark

I want to train a ML model to classify 141 application in a network traffic dataset using Pyspark using the following code:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="label",featuresCol="Scaled_features",numTrees = 200,maxDepth = 8,maxBins = 32)
rfModel = rf.fit(trainDF)
rf_predictions = rfModel.transform(testDF)
```

I encountered the following error:

requirement failed: Classifier inferred 139 from label values in column RandomForestClassifier_a915d3f8a3c4__labelCol, but this exceeded the max numClasses (100) allowed to be inferred from values.  To avoid this error for labels with > 100 classes, specify numClasses explicitly in the metadata; this can be done by applying StringIndexer to the label column.

[image]

Prior to this code part, I do string indexer as follows:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="web_service", outputCol="label")
indexer.setHandleInvalid("skip")  # Handles unseen labels
df = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
```

**Update:**
I tried this and it doesn't work, an error occurred.

```
num_classes = 141  # The actual number of classes in your label column
dt_classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol="indexed_label", featuresCol="features", numClasses=num_classes)
```

Comment: when do you get this error. I am guessing while evaluating or predicting. Am I right?

Comment: In the prediction stage (the training stage). I face the same error using decision Tree algorithm.

Comment: in prediction stage or training stage

Comment: I just edit the question. I think it is the training stage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's an error which can break your code. To make it easy, you can always write the no of labels/classes that you have.

Comment: how can I specify the no. of classes?

Comment: Actually you did it here:num_classes = 141  # The actual number of classes in your label column
dt_classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol="indexed_label", featuresCol="features", numClasses=num_classes)

Comment: However, it does not work. An error occurred.

Comment: Actually, the image that you shared that says that you need to set up numClasses > 100 manually in metadata. I am no pyspark expert but I think that's what you need to do by looking at it.